# How to save multi selection after left/right click in primefaces's datatable?

Tags: datatable, primefaces, selection, multi-select

I look at this [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf) and dont understand how to save selection after user click on one of already selected rows. So for example when user select 3 rows and make a click on one of this it will be show information about only one selected rows.

Now I have DataTable with lazy loading and context menu like this:

```
                <p:dataTable id="al_table" value="#{alarmTable.alarms}"
                    selection="#{alarmTable.selectedAlarm}" selectionMode="multiple"
                    var="alarm" resizableColumns="true" paginator="true" rows="50"
                    sortBy="#{alarm.alarmTimestamp}" sortOrder="descending"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="25, 50, 75, 100" lazy="true"
                    style="table-layout: auto">

                    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" update=":form:display"
                        oncomplete="alarmDialog.show()" />
```

And all work very well except selection. With this behavior like now i can't do any action with multi rows at the same time, because it always lose selection. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in current implementation. You should use buttons not in context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a DataModel to manage your selection. see this [Sample](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) which works with all Single and Double click events.

Comment: thanks for the notification. I have updated the link